# Matlab system function not running the command and not returning any values

Tags: php, matlab

I have the following set up: on Mac OS X, Apache invokes a PHP script, which uses the `system` function to call a Matlab script, which in turn has its own `system` invocation to call some shell commands.

However, it seems that no commands actually run (I tried a simple echo into a file), and when I try to capture the output of the command using the `[status, cmdout] = system()` signature, `status` and `cmdout` end up being empty.

This doesn't happen if I run the Matlab script manually from the command line (the echo and all other `system` calls run as normal).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

PHP code:

```
$system_call_string_2 = "matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -r 'run ../users/".$user."/projects/".$project."/processing.m' > /dev/null &";
system($system_call_string_2);
```

processing.m calls a function form a file called data_file_load_online.m:

```
system(['grep "CGHv1_Ca_\|CGH_Ca_" ' file_dir '/' file_name ' > ' file_dir '/CGH_rows.xls']);
```

To be clear, I've already checked that this code is reached, the path is correct, substituted the command for an echo into a file, and ran the Matlab script manually to make sure that it does work that way.

Comment: Can you show us a more detailed code?

Comment: Do you have permissions to read file_dir and file_name when it is run from apache?

Comment: @Navan, yes - these directories and files are all created by PHP itself, and are owned by the _www user. But even if this was a permission thing, I'd expect there to be an error output from Matlab's 'system' calls.

Comment: Yes. There would be an error if the permission were not correct. I do not have any more ideas. I assume you have checked grep is producing some results for that command.